# Convert WKT to image

Tags: python, convert, well-known-text

Is there any way to convert WKT like

`MULTILINESTRING ((48.8744070530328 34.71707055692468, 49.127092599907755 34.72892221300337, 48.89363312725153 34.70987407974113, 48.93002533916562 34.63632126493155, 48.87646698955628 34.715941739168706))`

to image?

Something like WMS GetMap request.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

In the [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) manual you can find published code on how you could generate images from geometry objects (that could be constructed by WKT).

[linestring.py](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code/linestring.py)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString

from figures import SIZE

COLOR = {
    True:  '#6699cc',
    False: '#ffcc33'
    }

def v_color(ob):
    return COLOR[ob.is_simple]

def plot_coords(ax, ob):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='#999999', zorder=1)

def plot_bounds(ax, ob):
    x, y = zip(*list((p.x, p.y) for p in ob.boundary))
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='#000000', zorder=1)

def plot_line(ax, ob):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, color=v_color(ob), alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)

fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=SIZE, dpi=90)

# 1: simple line
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 0)])

plot_coords(ax, line)
plot_bounds(ax, line)
plot_line(ax, line)

ax.set_title('a) simple')

xrange = [-1, 4]
yrange = [-1, 3]
ax.set_xlim(*xrange)
ax.set_ylim(*yrange)
ax.set_yticks(list(range(*yrange)) + [yrange[-1]])
ax.set_aspect(1)

#2: complex line
ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
line2 = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 2), (-1, 1), (1, 0)])

plot_coords(ax, line2)
plot_bounds(ax, line2)
plot_line(ax, line2)

ax.set_title('b) complex')

xrange = [-2, 3]
yrange = [-1, 3]
ax.set_xlim(*xrange)
ax.set_ylim(*yrange)
ax.set_yticks(list(range(*yrange)) + [yrange[-1]])
ax.set_aspect(1)

pyplot.show()
```